# How to toggle different forms in NetBeans GUI design

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, netbeans

I'm using *NetBeans 8 IDE* to design a desktop application. How can I transit among different forms (e.g. *login page* and *homepage*)? Should I design multiple `.java` *JForms* or is it possible to completely delete previous components and bring new ones?

Is there something like hidden tabs that aren't shown to the user but really exist? I am looking for a high performance way to toggle forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you to have the form constructed programmatically - although this is a bit inefficient - you could use a switch statement in a loop with cases that contain the individual forms, and statements to clear the existing form components.  There's also an easy JavaFX navigation solution using a larger-than-viewport area (containing each form in a horizontal series) wherein the forms get the viewport one-by-one, but it looks like you're using swing; sorry if it's of no help in this case.